# How to know what link/button was clicked and then replace the content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a simple JQuery script that will change the text of a button/link.
However, with the code that I have, only the first link of the matching ID will ever be changed.

For example, I have 10 links with the ID "coupon-link". When a user presses one of them, the attribute "coupon-code" should replace the current content of the link with the coupon code. Currently it only runs once, and it also replaces only the first link - even if I press the second or third one.

This is what I have right now:

```
// Coupon button checker
$("#coupon-link").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("coupon-clicked");

    alert($(this).attr('coupon-code'));

    if (!$(this).hasClass("coupon-shown") && $(this).hasClass("coupon-clicked")) {
        // Replace the text with the coupon code
        $(".coupon-clicked").html("<b>Rabattkod: " + $(this).attr('coupon-code') + "</b>");

        // This one has been unveiled
        $(".coupon-clicked").addClass("coupon-shown");

        // Remove the clicked class
        $(".coupon-clicked").removeClass("coupon-clicked");
    }
});
```

So my problem is basically, how do I run the .click for each seperate link?
How can I make it so that when link #1 is pressed, the attribute of link #1 is replaced with its content, and the same goes for #2 and #3 and so on?

Comment: *I have 10 links with the ID "coupon-link".* then what you have, my friend, is invalid HTML; and you should expect no browser to handle that with any predictable sanity. Use a `class`, an `id` [***must be unique within the document***](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

Comment: Please post an example of your HTML as well.

Comment: I didn't think that JQuery was unable to traverse them. I understand now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You [can not have](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) 10 links with the same id. Turn id="coupon-link" to class="coupon-link" and use

```
$(".coupon-link").click(function() {
//code
```

Comment: You can , but you should not :)

Answer (score 0):

Ids should be unique for every tag in the page. Even though you can achieve your goal by using this selector:

```
$("a[id=coupon-link]").click(function() {
//
```

Comment: Although it's true that ids should be unique, a better approach for that would be $('a#coupon-link').click()

Comment: That code has the goal of selecting multiple elements with a given id. If you use the #id selector it will only selects the first element  found with the given id.